# Losing DST information using pytz and UTC conversions

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, utc, pytz

Maybe this is a 4am bug, but I *think* I'm doing everything right, but it doesn't appear as though DST is translating from the UTC timestamp to the localized datetime.

```python
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> import pytz
>>> eastern = pytz.timezone("US/Eastern")
>>> utc = pytz.utc
>>> local_now = eastern.localize(datetime.now())
>>> utc_now = local_now.astimezone(utc)
>>> seconds = int(utc_now.strftime("%s"))
>>> utc_then = utc.localize(datetime.fromtimestamp(seconds))
>>> local_then = utc_then.astimezone(eastern)
>>> print utc_now, utc_then
2013-06-16 10:05:27.893005+00:00 2013-06-16 11:05:27+00:00
>>> print local_now, local_then
2013-06-16 06:05:27.893005-04:00 2013-06-16 07:05:27-04:00
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
             o------------o
             |            |  DT.datetime.utcfromtimestamp (*)
             |            |<-----------------------------------o
             |            |                                    |
             |  datetime  |                                    |
             |            |  DT.datetime.fromtimestamp         |
             |            |<----------------------------o      |
             |            |                             |      |
             o------------o                             |      |
                |   ^                                   |      |
     .timetuple |   |                                   |      |
  .utctimetuple |   | DT.datetime(*tup[:6])             |      |
                v   |                                   |      |
             o------------o                          o------------o
             |            |-- calendar.timegm (*) -->|            |
             |            |                          |            |
             |            |---------- time.mktime -->|            |
             |  timetuple |                          |  timestamp |
             |            |<-- time.localtime -------|            |
             |            |                          |            |
             |            |<-- time.gmtime (*)-------|            |
             o------------o                          o------------o

(*) Interprets its input as being in UTC and returns output in UTC
```

As the diagram shows, when you have a datetime in UTC such as `utc_now`, to get its timestamp, use

```
seconds = calendar.timegm(utc_date.utctimetuple())
```

When you have a timestamp, to get to the datetime in UTC, use

```
DT.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(seconds)
```

---

```
import datetime as DT
import pytz
import calendar
eastern = pytz.timezone("US/Eastern")
utc = pytz.utc
now = DT.datetime(2013, 6, 16, 10, 0, 0)
local_now = eastern.localize(now)
utc_now = local_now.astimezone(utc)
seconds = calendar.timegm(utc_now.utctimetuple())

print(seconds)
# 1371391200

utc_then = utc.localize(DT.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(seconds))
local_then = utc_then.astimezone(eastern)

print utc_now, utc_then
# 2013-06-16 14:00:00+00:00 2013-06-16 14:00:00+00:00
print local_now, local_then
# 2013-06-16 10:00:00-04:00 2013-06-16 10:00:00-04:00
```

PS. Note that the `timetuple()` and `utctimetuple()` methods drop microseconds off the datetime. To convert a datetime to a timestamp in a way that preserves microseconds, use [mata's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1350899/mata).

Answer (score 4):

You should avoid `datetime.now` if you want to write portable code, as it always uses the local timezone, so `local_now = eastern.localize(datetime.now())` will only work if the timezone on the local machine *is* eastern. Always try to use `utcnow`, and for the same reason `utcfromtimestamp`.

Also, using `strftime("%s")` to convert a datetime to a timestamp doesn't work.

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

utc_now = pytz.utc.localize(datetime.utcnow())
eastern = pytz.timezone("US/Eastern")
local_now = utc_now.astimezone(eastern)

# seconds = utc_now.timestamp()  python3
seconds = (utc_now - pytz.utc.localize(datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0))).total_seconds()
utc_then = pytz.utc.localize(datetime.utcfromtimestamp(seconds))

local_then = utc_then.astimezone(eastern)

print("%s - %s" % (utc_now, utc_then))
print("%s - %s" % (local_now, local_then))
```

Comment: `datetime(1970, 1, 1, tzinfo=pytz.utc)` might be more explicit than `pytz.utc.localize(datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0))`. I'm not sure that stdlib can work with other epoch value anyway.

Answer (score 0):

To get your local timezone as `pytz.timezone` object, you could use `tzlocal` module:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from datetime import datetime
import pytz # pip install pytz
from tzlocal import get_localzone # pip install tzlocal

local_tz = get_localzone()
local_now = datetime.now(local_tz)
utc_now = local_now.astimezone(pytz.utc)
seconds = (utc_now - datetime(1970, 1, 1, tzinfo=pytz.utc)).total_seconds()

utc_then = datetime.fromtimestamp(seconds, pytz.utc)
local_then = utc_then.astimezone(local_tz)
print("%s %s" % (utc_now, utc_then))
print("%s %s" % (local_now, local_then))
```

- don't use `datetime.now()` -- it may be ambiguous e.g., during DST change. Either pass tzinfo explicitly as in my example or use `datetime.utcnow()`
- don't use `utc_now.strftime('%s')` --  [it ignores timezone info (it uses the current local timezone)](http://bugs.python.org/issue12750) and it is not portable. Use [`datetime.timestamp()` method or its analogs instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8778548/4279)
- don't use `utc.localize(datetime.fromtimestamp(seconds))` -- `.fromtimestamp()` returns a naive datetime object in local timezone that may be different from UTC. Either pass tzinfo explicitly as in my example or use `datetime.utcfromtimestamp()` to get a naive datetime object that represents UTC time
- don't use `datetime.utctimetuple()` with naive datetime objects -- it doesn't convert them to UTC. If the object is already in UTC: `utc_now.timetuple()` returns the same time.

To raise an exception for ambiguous local time, use `localize(is_dst=None)`:

```
aware_dt = tz.localize(naive_dt, is_dst=None)
```

Without `is_dst=None`, there is 50% chance that `tz.localize()` returns wrong result during DST change. If it is preferable to get a possibly wrong result instead of an exception in your particular case then you could pass the explicit `is_dst=False` to remind yourself about it.

In general, [`pytz` documentation](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/) recommends `tz.normalize()` after `.astimezone()` call if neither source nor destination timezones are UTC.